# Using data.table in R, can I select a vector of variable columns from a table?

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a table like:

```
> A = data.table(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6),c(7,8,9))
> A
    V1 V2 V3
1:  1  4  7
2:  2  5  8
3:  3  6  9
```

I want to select the first column of the first row, second of the second row and third of the third row, getting the result:

```
> B
[1] 1 5 9
```

I've tried something like:

```
B = A[,c(1,2,3)]
```

But that does not work. Is it possible to do this? (Obviously in my actual use case the column indexes for each row are going to be variables, but I can guarantee a vector of length equal to the number of rows in the table)

Comment: works for this specific example, but what if the columns I want are c(1,1,2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vectorized way of subsetting the elements is by providing the row index and column index as a matrix

```
as.data.frame(A)[cbind(seq_len(nrow(A)), 1:3)]
#[1] 1 5 9
```

Or convert the `.SD` to `matrix` or `data.frame` and use the row/column index

```
A[, as.matrix(.SD)[cbind(1:3, 1:3)]]
```

---

Or in `data.table`, pass the `i`, `j` index in a loop and extract the elements

```
A[, unlist(Map(function(i, j) .SD[i, j, with = FALSE], 1:3, 1:3), 
          use.names = FALSE)]
```

Comment: last one is exactly what I need, thanks! 

To generalize for anyone looking for this later, the first 1:3 in the @akrun solution is a vector of row ids and the second is a vector of column ids. Both can be replaced by lists, and can feature repetitions or not include every vector, but they must be the same length. For example,
A[, unlist(Map(function(i, j) .SD[i, j, with = FALSE], c(2,2,1,3), c(2,3,2,1)), use.names = FALSE)]
returns:
[1] 5 8 4 3